# How do i know that which button is clicked in flex?

Tags: apache-flex

```
             for (iss = 0; iss < listOfProductIds2.length; iss++)
        {
            // Alert.show(listOfProductIds2[iss]);
                        var productMain:VBox=new VBox();
             var p1:HBox=new HBox();
             var l1:Label=new Label();
             var b1:Button=new Button();
             var spacer:Spacer=new Spacer();
             spacer.width=300;
             b1.label="Remove";
             b1.setConstraintValue("id","");
             b1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,removeProduct); 
             l1.text="Product "+iss;
             p1.setActualSize(500,500);
             p1.addChild(l1);
             p1.addChild(spacer);
             p1.addChild(b1);
             productMain.addChild(p1);  
        }

          function removeProduct(event:MouseEvent):void
    { 
        // How do i know which button is clicked 
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `event.currentTarget` (instead of `event.target`) because [event.target](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#event:click) might be the `Label` component or some styling component within the button, but `currentTarget` is assured to be the object with which the listener was registered.

To get a handle to the button that was clicked you can just cast the `currentTarget` to a button.

```
function removeProduct(event:MouseEvent):void
{ 
    var b1:Button = Button(event.currentTarget);
}
```

The method `setConstraintValue` is for setting layout constraints, not setting id. The `id` property is used by mxml for creating variable names for objects. You can get/set `id` as you would get/set any other property (say width) - but neither have I seen anyone doing that nor do I see any need to do that in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the info about currentTarget. 

In this situation, setting the id could be interesting as the buttons are created dynamically, so for example : 

b1.id = "button_" + listOfProductIds2[iss];

.. then later you can check the id of the button to see which one was clicked. (Although that's not very clean, since it mixes id with business-related info.)

I suppose the problem here is to know the productId corresponding to the button. Lots of way to do it... One could have a ProductButton class with a product id as a public, know property ... or some maps between product Ids and Buttons ?

Answer (score 0):

event.target should point to the Button you clicked on, shouldn't it ? However you should probably give ids to the buttons to be able to differenciate them (since you create them dynamically.)

Comment: ok it's fine .. but how do i know that which id u have clicked

Answer (score 0):

Look at `event.target`.

Answer (score 0):

If ids are assigned dynamically as in the example given `b1.id = "button_" + listOfProductIds2[iss]`
Then the function that processes the click event would look at the currenttarget, and what I usually do is do a string replace on the part of the id that you know is not dynamic like `"button_"` with `""`, which leaves you with the name of the product.